# Error The key was not found in the key ring + Blazor(Wasm) + DataProtection

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-3.1, data-protection

I configured the blazor (wasm) to use the DataProtection with the PersistKeysToFileSystem method

[image: PersistKeysToFileSystem]

So I start the server and everything works fine, except for two things:

1. The file is not saved in the directory

[image]

2. When I restart the server the key restarts the following error happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would be surprised if a C:\temp is allowed by browser sandbox on client or even on server